# angularjs: variables in service not updating for service or controller

Tags: angularjs

JavaScript and AngularJS is still new to me.

I have trouble getting variables from my services into my scope. Here is what I'm doing:

```
myControllers.controller('UserController', function($scope, UserService) {

    clearLoginForm();
    updateStuff();
    $scope.notifications = UserService.notifications;

    function updateStuff() {
        $scope.realName = UserService.realName;
        $scope.loggedIn = UserService.loggedIn;
    }

    function clearLoginForm() {
        $scope.loginName = '';
        $scope.loginPassword = '';
    }

    $scope.login = function() {
        UserService.login($scope.loginName,$scope.loginPassword);
        updateStuff();
        clearLoginForm();
    }

    $scope.logout = function() {
        UserService.logout();
        updateStuff();
        clearLoginForm();
    }

});
```

the UserService should hold the information about the logged in User and the functions for login/logout and account related stuff that should be polled from the server.

```
myModule.factory('UserService', function($interval) {

      var loggedIn = false;
      var realName = "";
      var notifications = {};
      resetNotifications();

      function resetNotifications() {
          notifications.msgCount = 0;
          notifications.todoCount = 0;
          notifications.ergCount = 0;
      }

      function login(name, password) {
          if (password === 'abc') {
              loggedIn = true;
              realName = 'John Smith';
          }
      };

      function logout() {
          loggedIn = false;
          realName = '';
          resetNotifications();
      }


      function updateNotifications() {
          if (loggedIn) {
              notifications.msgCount = 1;
          }
          else {
              resetNotifications();
          }
      };

      $interval(updateNotifications, 10000);

      return {
          loggedIn : loggedIn,
          realName : realName,
          login : login,
          logout : logout,
          notifications : notifications
      };
  });
```

But it's not working. So I noticed that if I change "loggedIn" in the login/logout functions to "this.loggedIn" (and same with realName) then the values get propagated to the scope. Why do I need the "this"? Aren't "loggedIn" and "realName" in my closure? But this is not a solution since this is now a different "loggedIn" than used in the updateNotifications function (and here I can't change it to "this.loggedIn").

Secondly, I don't like that I need to call the updateStuff() Function everytime a value in the service changes. But it's not working without. Is there a better way to do it?

I fear I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return `loggedIn` at the end of your service, what you're really returning is a copy of the variable. So when you later update it inside of UserService, the copy won't get updated. The easiest way to solve that is with the getter approach:

```
function getLoggedIn() { return loggedIn; }

return {
    getLoggedIn: getLoggedIn
};
```

Answer (score 2):

your answer helped. but I found a better way to do it. I just wrapped loggedIn and realName in a real object

```
var userStatus = {
        loggedIn : false,
        realName : ""
      };
```

and using that one in the controller. That also removes the necessity of the updateStuff function. I hope that won't cause any other trouble.

Comment: This is also a perfectly fine way to do it.